# Please pluralize [keyboard-shortcut]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [keyboard-shortcut](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) would be better as [keyboard-shortcuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) because, well, an app seldom has a single keyboard shortcut.

It would also better match other tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have merged [keyboard-shorcut](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shorcut) into [keyboard-shortcuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) and made the former a synonym.

I also copied over the old tag wiki, but feel free to make any modifications to it as necessary.